# Connecting two queries in one table in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 queries

```
SELECT date_format(payments.paymentdate, '%m'), 
       SUM(payments.amount) 
FROM payments 
WHERE payments.`customerNumber` IN 
(
    SELECT customers.`customerNumber` 
    FROM customers 
    WHERE customers.`country` = 'USA' 
    and customers.`customerNumber` = payments.`customerNumber`
)
GROUP BY date_format(payments.paymentdate, '%m')
```

AND

```
SELECT date_format( payments.paymentdate, '%m') , 
       SUM( payments.amount )
FROM payments
GROUP BY date_format( payments.paymentdate, '%m')
```

They return results, so everything is OK. However, I need to get a result with 3 columns - `date_format(payments.paymentdate, '%m')`, `SUM(payments.amount) (where country is USA)` and   `SUM(payments.amount)` (with all the countries).

I've tried the following query

```
SELECT date_format( payments.paymentdate, '%m') , 
       SUM(payments.amount ), 
       (
          SELECT SUM(payments.amount) 
          FROM payments 
          WHERE payments.`customerNumber` IN 
          (
             SELECT customers.`customerNumber` 
             FROM customers WHERE customers.`country` = 'USA' 
             and customers.`customerNumber` = payments.`customerNumber`
          )
       )
FROM payments
GROUP BY date_format( payments.paymentdate, '%m')
```

But I have the total SUM of payments from USA, not sums by months.

How may I fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: Use Table alias and try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the sum of all Payments and the sum of some payments.

That's perfect for an "if" statement. I still suppose you want '%Y-%m' sooner or later, not to mix up April 2014 and April 2015.

```
SELECT date_format(payments.paymentdate, '%m') as month, SUM(payments.amount) as amount_total, sum(if(customers.country='USA', payments.amount, 0)) as amount_USA
FROM payments 
inner join customers on customers.customerNumber = payments.customerNumber
GROUP BY date_format(payments.paymentdate, '%m')
```

Comment: @user3556682: If it's good, then you can mark the answer as correct and and if it helps you, you could upvote it. That's where we have the reputation score from. ;-)